# How to reinstall VSCode without losing extensions and user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

After being updated to 1.9.0, some features of the editor just stopped working here. I tried to run with `--disable-extensions` option and the problem persisted.

Now I want to reinstall to check if the installation is corrupted but I don't want to lose my preferences.

How can I reinstall VSCode keeping my extensions and user settings?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find all settings and preferences for visual studio code here: C:\Users[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Code

You'll notice some cache directories there. You may try clearing those before a reinstall. My intellisense and formatting randomly quit working all the time and clearing the cache fixes my issues.

Comment: After many days I got a solution. `rm -rf /c/users/[username]/appdata/roaming/code/cache/*` and now it is working fine. Really thank you!

Comment: glad I could help!

Comment: holy shoot! My vscode was slow as a pumpkin! Now it's bananas fast!

Answer (score 36):

I just downloaded vsCode again and installed over the top of my existing install.

This preserved everything and fixed my "Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall." issue.

Answer (score 4):

I uninstalled and re-installed and my settings all seemed preserved.
Some Extensions were disabled but still, it seems to work smoothly with no loss in extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `setting sync` feature to save your extensions and your settings. Before you reinstall vscode, login to your github or gg account and turn on sync mode. Of course after you reinstall, you must login and turn on sync mode to see the changing. I have tried it and actually it works!

Answer (score 1):

For me, deleting the cache did not work. Downloading and re-installing VScode again without uninstalling it helped, but I lost all my extensions and individual settings :/ It solved my issue, though.

Comment: VSCode has Settings Sync now, in the settings cog, sign in with your Github account and you can sync everything.

Comment: @misterrodger doesn't work for me, that's the intention in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin `Settings Sync`. Saves every config & setting & workspace & keybinding.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in the settings: **Setting>Search>Max Results**. It was set to 20000. If what you are searching for is huge, leaving it empty might make your computer stuck for keep searching. But for my case ~400,000, it did not bother.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in suggested has been deprecated:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync

There's a built-in feature now: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync